# How to set tag attribute with value from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have img tag in the view and I want to set the src attribute of that img with value from model object like that:

```
    @model myObject

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "title";
    }  

   <img src="@Model.mysrc" alt="error"  />
```

but it's not work and I try to use jquery but not work too:

```
$('img').attr("src", "@Model.mysrc");
```

Comment: `but it not work`. any exception? or error in desgin time? canyou post the relevant actioresult from the controller?

Comment: try my solution that is given below.

Comment: Shouldn't it be myObject.mysrc?

Comment: Can you show us your "myObject" class ?

Comment: the problem was because of the string in the @Model.mysrc =  "~/images/photo.jpg"
 it is tilde, i remove tilde and it work right, 
thank you all

Comment: i try to answer my question but i cannot i do not know why ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it was related to a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of the string in the @Model.mysrc = "~/images/photo.jpg"

it is **tilde**, i remove **tilde** and it work right,